# Cannot access serialized content from medium-editor in js

Tags: javascript, medium-editor

I'm using the medium-editor in combination with the medium-editor-insert-plugin. According to the documentation, it's possible to access the clean content like this:

```
var allContents = editor.serialize();
var elContent = allContents["element-0"].value;
```

However, when I try to do this I get the following error:

[image]

When I simply print out `editor.serialize()` I get the following element:

[image]

The number behind `medium-editor-...` seems to be changing every time and I also cannot access it with `allContents[0]`.

Does anyone know, how I can fix this or at least access the value attribute?

Comment: My guess is `element-0` is a reference, not a value. `element-0` should be equal to "medium-editor-1522..."

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Also thought of that but this number changes on every page reload.

Comment: Ok, apparently there is no other way. I figured out that the div has the same id so I now access it with `$('.medium-editor-element').first().attr('id');`